# Creating a left join in Django with null values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I'm trying to create a Django equivalent of a SQL `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. However I'm having trouble with this.

```py
class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Grades(models.Model):
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=3)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What my goal is, is to loop over all courses and when there is a value for the student (which I already have) then print out his/her grade. It seems really easy to me but I just cannot figure it out...

**EDIT:**

Bit more explanation:
I just have the student id, that's what I meant by which I already have. I need to print out all the Courses in a table (which is in an template)

So you'll get:

English - 8.0
French -
German - 10

So in this case no grade was set for French, therefor no grade will be shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "which I already have"? Can you give an example of something that you've tried and it's failed? I think a bit more context around your usage would clarify how to best answer your question. Otherwise it's going to be `prefetch_related` or use a `Grades` queryset.

Comment: So, you have student values?  Why loop over all courses?  Why not just look at the Grades class?

Comment: @schillingt and Rachel Please check my edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `prefetch_related` with a restricted queryset.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
courses = Course.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('grades_set', queryset=Grade.objects.filter(student=my_student))
)
```

Now when you iterate over courses, `course.grade_set.all()` will only contain grades related to `my_student`.

Comment: Could you explain how I would to this in a template? So I've got this: `{% for course in courses %} <tr><td>{{ course }}</td><td>value</td></tr>{% endfor %}` How would I replace value with the grade?

Comment: Which will print the same grade for everyline? As far as I know, you can't use `{{ forloop.counter0 }}` either or am I wrong about that?

Comment: Why would it print the same grade for every line? The prefetch has fetched the relevant grade for your student for that course.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a subquery annotation over `Course`.

You have a n:1 relation between `Grades` and `Course`, meaning that there could be 0 to n `Grades` instances returned for one `Course`. This is still true from a DB perspective, even if you reduce it to the courses of one student.

The business logic probably says that you can only have one grade per course and student but you have no such restriction on your DB (you could add a `unique_together = ['course', 'student']`) but you'll probably still need to keep this fact in mind for the annotation.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Max

# student => which you already have
# Max() added because the subquery must ever only return 1 hit
# otherwise an error is raised
grade_query = Grades.objects.filter(course=OuterRef('pk'), student=student).annotate(
    max_grade=Max('grade')).values('max_grade')
Course.objects.annotate(
    student_grade=Subquery(grade_query, output_field=CharField())
).values('name', 'student_grade')
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

---

### SQL Statements / Performance

A note on how many SQL statements are triggered depending on the solution because of the comments.

#### Plain ORM

```
for course in Course.objects.all():
    grade = course.grades_set.filter(student=student).first() or ''
    print(f'{course.name}: {grade}')
```

This results in:

- 1 query for all course objects
- +1 for each course objects to fetch the grades for this student and this course

Alltogether, if there are 20 courses this will result in 21 SQL selects.

#### Prefetch Related

Changing `Course.objects.all()` to Daniel Roseman's suggestion (very good one!):

```
Course.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('grades_set', queryset=Grade.objects.filter(student=my_student))
)
```

results in 2 SQL selects:

- 1 for the courses
- 1 for all the grades for all courses for this specific student

The ORM layer takes care to merge the results of both queries.

(Much better, and the most flexible solution.)

#### Annotate/Aggregation

Results in exactly 1 SQL select.

You need to know what you want in advance, and if performance is an issue and you want to avoid additional SQL selects at all costs, `values()` makes sure of that as it does not yield any Model instances but simple values, and only SELECTs exactly those values and not anything else (like more related models that trigger unnecessary joins).

If the result is only needed in a template for display, fetched in a view and not intended for anything else, it's a good choice.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but this seems way to over complicated and quite an harsh performance hit. Is there any way to make it simpler?

Comment: @Risadinha You can avoid using max by doing `.values('grade')[:1]` which should be better. @MrDikke It's definitely a more complicated way of doing things, but I wouldn't say there's a harsh performance hit.

Comment: Why would there be a performance hit? Please provide proof. A decent database does annotations just fine. It's joins on foreign keys which are indexed by default, and it's in a single query and you fetch only what you need.

Comment: @schillingt - I've chosen Max() because there is no order. Max() is not nice of course because it is a string and ordering of the grades might follow some other rules than natural string order. If there really is a unique_together constraint on the table, it wouldn't matter though, as there would only ever be one entry.

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong, the performance hit is most likely not that bad. When first going over this answer I felt like it were 2 separate queries. But they're not... I'm sorry!

Comment: @MrDikke - I've added an explanation on what SQL statements are triggered by which solution.

Comment: @Risadinha You deserved an upvote for that one, thanks for the explanation. Actually helps me out!